# Regex for 12 Hour Timestamp along with support for time-end

Tags: regex, time

Been trying to get this regex to work properly but can't seem to do it.

I need the regex to basically pick up these combinations of times:

```
12am
12:30am
12am - 12pm
12:30am - 1:30am
12:30 - 1:30am
12 - 1:30am
```

If I add a ? behind my ([a|p]m) section, the regex will match numbers which I don't want it to do.

Here is my regex code:

```
(?:(1[012]|[1-9]):([0-5][0-9])|(1[012]|[1-9])) ?([a|p]m)(?:\s-\s(?:(1[012]|[1-9]):([0-5][0-9])|(1[012]|[1-9])) ?([a|p]m))?
```

Any help is appreciated, thank you.

Comment: wont https://regex101.com/r/gN1qS7/3 suffice?

Comment: You needed to add `?` in some places (see [demo](https://regex101.com/r/cN7yK1/1)).

Comment: @rock321987 this seems to do the trick, however it still picks up "12" on its own, I'm running this regex through email content and it will match a date for example: "12 February"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This does the work:

```
((?:1[0-2]|\d)(?:\:[0-5]\d)?(?:[ap]m)?)[\s-]+((?:1[0-2]|\d)(?:\:[0-5]\d)?(?:[ap]m)?)
```

<kbd>[Live Demo](https://regex101.com/r/pF9sG6/2)</kbd>.

Explanation (second group is the same as the first one):

```
1st Capturing group ((?:1[0-2]|\d)(?:\:[0-5]\d)?(?:[ap]m))

(?:1[0-2]|\d) Non-capturing group
    1st Alternative: 1[0-2]
        1 matches the character 1 literally
        [0-2] match a single character present in the list below
            0-2 a single character in the range between 0 and 2
    2nd Alternative: \d
        \d match a digit [0-9]
(?:\:[0-5]\d)? Non-capturing group
    Quantifier: ? Between zero and one time, as many times as possible, giving back as needed [greedy]
    \: matches the character : literally
    [0-5] match a single character present in the list below
        0-5 a single character in the range between 0 and 5
    \d match a digit [0-9]
(?:[ap]m) Non-capturing group
    [ap] match a single character present in the list below
        ap a single character in the list ap literally (case insensitive)
    m matches the character m literally (case insensitive)

[\s-]+ match a single character present in the list below

Quantifier: + Between one and unlimited times, as many times as possible, giving back as needed [greedy]
\s match any white space character [\r\n\t\f ]
- the literal character -
```

Comment: I probably typed this stupid, but I need all 4 examples to be picked up using the regex 12 - 1:30pm isn't picked up when it should be.

Comment: I've edited the above post with more examples, I also require the regex to pick up "12am" along with  "12am - 1:30am" etc, if that's possible in the one regex.

Comment: That's what it does now @JohnnyDoey

Comment: @JohnnyDoey this isn't my regex.